# How to get url value after #

Tags: php, session, url

I am using `PHP` for my website. i want to fetch URL value that is like `test/show.php?ID=247#about`.

when i used session variable

```
<?php

 session_start();
 $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

echo $url;

?>
```

its printing only  `test/show.php?ID=247`.

i am not getting `#about`. this #about i want to used to redirect my main page menu.

Please can any one tell me how to get it.

thank you.

Comment: To elaborate on the answers provided below, you could always onpageload pass the variable through an ajax call to a php file, and then process it somehow.

Comment: This is a very bad idea because it is NOT saved in search engine indexes. In other words, your `page#1`, `page#2`, ... `page#n` will all be recorded as one page: `page`. Do not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access tis part (hash) in PHP, you can access it using JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.location.hash)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot - without custom client-side support<sup>1</sup>

The ["hash" (or Fragment Identifier)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) is *not sent* to the server normally.

> The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the URI: namely, *its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from the web server* .. When an agent (such as a Web browser) requests a web resource from a Web server, the agent sends the URI to the server, but *does not send the fragment*. Instead, the agent waits for the server to send the resource, and then the agent processes the resource according to the document type and fragment value.

---

<sup>1</sup> You could, for instance, use JavaScript hook into the form `submit` event, read from [`window.location.hash`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952653.aspx) as appropriate, and shove the value into a control for the form submission .. however, the general design should be rethought (or rather, avoided) for several reasons:

1. Hash changes are generally used for client-side state management and "AJAX" navigation.
2. Increased complexity, and unexpected/browser-subversive behavior.
3. It won't work on "normal" links or on the first page load after navigation.

Comment: thank you. can you please tell me how you will do this using custom JavaScript on the client?